# Getting access denied while AWS cli setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have created a user in IAM with admin access but still getting access denied while AWS cli setup.

EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/asit/.aws/credentials'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be due to the wrong permissions on the `/home/asit/.aws/credentials`.

You can fix the permissions by running the below command.

```sh
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/asit/.aws/
```

I am assuming you have followed this doc [Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) for configuring the CLI.